# The tooltip opens at the same place irrespective of the layout area in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, css

I have a Tooltip which on mouse over opens on the top left side corner
of the page irrespectve of the 'mouseover'.
In case of IE8 this works fine and opens just above the place where mouse is 
placed but in Firefox its unable to calculate/interprete  the values.

here is the code snippet for tooltip

```
   function DoFlyOver()
{
  if( ToClear != -1 ) window.clearTimeout( ToClear );
  var thisForm = eval("document." + formName);
  if (FlyOverArea == null) FlyOverArea = document.getElementById("FlyOverArea");

    if (FlyOverArea.firstChild!==null)
        FlyOverArea.removeChild(FlyOverArea.firstChild); // remove all existing content
        FlyOverArea.appendChild(document.createTextNode(FoText));

    FoLeft = $displayOptions.getFlyoverLeftOfCursor();
        FoTop = $displayOptions.getFlyoverTopOfCursor();
    FlyOverArea.style.left = Number(thisForm.mousex.value) + Number(thisForm.scrollx.value) - Number(FoLeft);  
    FlyOverArea.style.top = Number(thisForm.mousey.value) + Number(thisForm.scrolly.value) - Number(FoTop);
    var maxX = (window.screen.width * $displayOptions.getFlyoverThreshold())/100;

// If the mouse is at the extreme right corner the max threshold should the tooltip be //placed.
   if(FlyOverArea.style.posLeft > (window.screen.width - maxX)){

    FlyOverArea.style.left = window.screen.width - maxX;
   }
    FlyOverArea.style.display = "";
    ToClear = setTimeout( "ClearFlyOver()", $displayOptions.getFlyoverVisibleTimeWithCursor(), "JAVASCRIPT" );//set timeout
}

    <DIV ID=FlyOverArea CLASS="FO" STYLE="display: none">
     </DIV>
```

I suspect its wih `style.top` and `style.left` and tried with `style.pixelLeft,style.posleft` too but no use

Comment: Have you debugged your code and looked at what the values are and how they differ from browser to browser? Not sure why you are storing values for the mouse position in a form field.

Comment: yes, i did use firebug, but not much use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha I found the answer,Mozilla cannot recognizes numbers but if you append with  `px` 
it will set the position. For example

```
var theLeft=Number(thisForm.mousex.value) + Number(thisForm.scrollx.value) - Number(FoLeft);
FlyOverArea.style.left = theLeft+"px"
```

This solved the problem